# Where is fuel metered in continuous flow fuel injection system?

Tags: turbine, fuel-systems

How is fuel metered in continuous flow fuel injection system?

Comment: Both questions.

Answer (score 4):

Just in front of the engine. It makes most sense to measure fuel flow as close to the engine as possible: any leaks between meter and engine will distort the measurement. Here is an example of the B737 arrangement.

[image: From own work based on on-line presentations]

As to the how, airborne fuel flow meters work in the same way that turbines do: the mass flow of the fuel causes an impeller to spin, rotational speed is then a measure of fuel flow. Note that it is a measure of fuel mass flow, not fuel volume flow: mass flow is not subject to variations due to temperature etc.